# Items don't zoom when using Flexbox with Browser Zoom

Tags: css, flexbox

I've inherited a site that uses Flexbox to achieve a basic 2 column layout. A user has noted that when you use the zoom feature of your browser the content around the flex displayed items zooms, but the flex items themselves actually shrink.

I have attempted to use flex-shrink set to 0, but that does not seem to solve the issue.

Here is a codepen illustrating the issue. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owGmEd

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use flexbox and still have browser zoom work as users expect. I could rewrite the code to ditch flexbox, but that seems like a heavy handed approach.

```css
div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/300x444" />
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/300x444" />
</div>
```

Comment: When I zoom in and out, so does the images. What is not zooming for you in that codepen?

Comment: When I zoom in using Chrome, this is what I see. Notice the images are small and the text is large. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tum0J.png

Comment: If you change to `display: inline-block` you'll see they also behave the same in the codepen.  You might want to use a more real sample, where both text and image are in your code, instead of compare how _codepen_ itself behave